# How to print Google Map markers

Tags: google-maps, printing, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map Version 3 API to add markers on Google Map.

The **problem** is that, markers show up on browsers. 
but when users print the map through browser's print command, nothing shows up.

The question is,
 - **How can I display markers on printed materials?** -

**Comparisons**:

- *On the browser* - markers are clearly visible
  [image]
- *After Print* (IE7, IE8) - markers are not printed (on paper or PDF)
  [image]
- *After Print* (FireFox 3.5.4) - only markers are printed
  [image]

Comment: @hsz: same result.  Since default didn't work, i tried custom marker

Comment: Have you tried to print in the other browser ?

Comment: @hsz: On FF 3.5.4, only markers are printed...

Comment: The reason they don't print is because the markers are div elements with `background-image:url('your_marker');` - you/your user has background image printing turned off. Looking for a solution myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you try out the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). You can build a [url](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps/info)  that will return a static image (you can build your custom markers into the URL).

The browser will do a much better job of printing an image than it will do with a dynamic Google map.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I construct static map URL, URL becames too long to be processed.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Static Maps has a maximum URL length of 2048 characters.  The docs mention that you should check you are encoding the URL correctly.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html#BuildingURLs Maybe worth checking. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to print markers by using [MarkerWithLabel](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js) in place of Google's Marker class which uses images in place of canvas.

Answer (score 1):

In my print dialog there is a checkbox "print background images". When I enable it, the markers are printed. This link can help you: [How can I force browsers to print background images in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

I had no issue with printing the markers. 
I've created my own markers and I use an `<IMG>` tag to stick the marker icon in.

The markers print fine on IE 8 on default settings.

Comment: Due to the printing issue, i deserted Google map over Bing map (silverlight version), which works fabulously well

Comment: I tried this but not working. Can you please include a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link given below:

https://gist.github.com/jawsthegame/6801698

Using this you will be able to print Google Map along with custom markers.

You only need to make a change at line number 17.
Replace container.clone(); with $(container).clone();

Comment: Could you give some insight in how to use this?