# Website logo isn't appearing on Print Stylesheet

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, stylesheet

The website is http://bit.ly/1h3C6yO

We're having some problems with print stylesheets. I have a print sheet defined, but when I go to print it, the logo is hidden.

I've searched for all Print media requests and am struggling to see what is causing this.

In addition, Safari prints out the image gallery just fine, but Chrome prints out the image gallery with thick full-width black bars around the images. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you have to enable printing of bg images?

Answer (score 0):

Background-images will not be printed. You can add the image with the `<img>` tag to let it print. More to read here: [How can I force browsers to print background images in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css)

Update:

To the problem with the bad borders at the image gallery, you should see in your CSS

```
.thumbnail {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
}
```

Try to add this to your `print.css`

```
.thumbnail {
    border: none;
}
```

Edit 2:

just thought abot the gallery border. I Guess it's more likely, that the default `a img` border is visible in the document. So if the above is not working, I'd recommend to try this (in your print.css):

```
.thumbnails a img
{
    border: none;
}
```