# Can I force phantomjs to render pdf's with the background images and colors

Tags: phantomjs

Using phantom JS 1.9.7 I am having issues printing my webpage to PDF.

Instead of matching the page exactly, background colors and images are stripped, as per:
[How can I force browsers to print background images in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to a post on another question, here is the answer:

```
body { 
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

You can add the CSS style "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;" to the element to force print the background color and/or image.

See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

Odd how this is on MDN.

Comment: Worth noting that adding `!important` to _color_ and _background_ definitions may be required for them to display properly. Thankfully it's quite easy to debug with Chrome's built in CSS media=print emulation.

Comment: Yeah, but this has pretty much NO support at all right now. You have to manually do `!important` in a `@media print` CSS block for all elements you want to keep their color/background.

Comment: i had to follow this answer to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15253634/1979461