# CSS styling lost when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, styling

I have a page which contains charts etc for statistics which must be printable. I want to just use the standard browser print functionality in order to enable printing. I also have css which changes the button colours for selected buttons to make it clear which charts are being viewed. However, my issue is that when i attempt to print the page, this colouring is lost and reset to its default presentation.

I am aware of the capabilities of doing this in Chrome by using webkit-print-color-adjust settings in the CSS, however, the vast majority of users in my business use IE or Edge (as they are microsoft defaults) and therefore i need a solution which would work in them.

I have attempted using !important and @media print but to no effect as yet, unless i am using them wrong.

Here is the css currently:

```
@media print{
    .btn-primary-chart:active,
    .btn-primary-chart.active {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: green !important;
        border-color: #285e8e;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: printing background colours is a browser setting and can only be turned on in the browser options as many people don't want to waste their colour ink on printing web pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS @media print issues with background-color;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)

Comment: So there is no possible way to do this? in this case, is there an alternative approach you could think of to display selected buttons when printing?

Comment: bit hacky but you could have a hidden image which you show (and hide the button) in your print stylesheet, or perhaps even use an image button

Comment: Im not sure i follow what you mean, could you provide an example in an answer for me to try please :)

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/e1hw9d35/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any foolproof method to print backgrounds in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge yet. However, there's a few methods I've tried before and may work under some circumstances:

**Method 1** (using sprite):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#fffad‌​a', endColorstr='#fffada')";
```

**Method 2**:

`CSS`

```
.background:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-bottom: 1000px solid #eee;
 }
```

`HTML`

```
<body class="background">
```

But if you want to print it yourself, you can enable 'Print Background Color':

> To resolve this behavior, turn on the Print background colors and images option in Internet Explorer. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options, and then click the Advanced tab.
> 2. In the Settings box, under Printing, click to select the Print background colors and images check box, and then click OK.

Also, a few similar StackOverFlow Posts

- [CSS @media print issues with background-color;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)
- [How can I force browsers to print background images in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css)

Answer (score 4):

From the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color), the reason why your CSS does not work is because of the default settings in the browser print settings.

With Chrome and Safari, you may want to add in

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

to force print the background color.

Comment: As mentioned in the question i worked out that setting is needed for chrome but the question was how to get it for IE and EDGE

Comment: @DaRoGa Tried `<style media="print" type="text/css">`?

Comment: I have yes. I am running out of ideas and may have to take a different approach judging by Pete's comments

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding "!important" on the style (but not in the @media print).

I just met the problem that font color was missing in print view, and the final solution is replace

```
color: red !;
```

with

```
color: red !important;
```

in the style.

It seems that some styles will be ignored if "!important" is not used.

Comment: Ignored probably isn't the right word here. Overridden would be more apt. `!important` ensures your styles are used rather than any printer defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that will even work in the EDGE browser.  Here is the basic HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative;width:100%">
     <div style="border-color:green;border-style:solid;
         border-width:15px;width:70%;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; 
                transform:translateY(-50%);left: 0px;">
         Hello, world.
     </div>
 </div>
```

You can adjust the width or the parent and the child div's as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning here, since I had a similar problem, is that EDGE will render SVG properly while ignoring the HTML background-color.

So instead of using:

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:20px height:20px">...</div>
```

You can use something like this:

```
<svg style="width:20px;height:20px">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:red">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to programmatically change the background printing setting for IE:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetPrintBackgroundSetting(CSettingsStore& regSettings, CString strPrintBackground, BOOL& rbResetDefault, BOOL& rbReset)
{
    rbResetDefault = FALSE;
    rbReset = FALSE;

    // Attempt to read the registry key value
    if(regSettings.Read(_T("Print_Background"), strPrintBackground))
    {
        // Update registry key value if we need to
        if (strPrintBackground != _T("yes"))
        {
            regSettings.Write(_T("Print_Background"), _T("yes"));

            // Remember, reset it back to original value afterwards
            rbReset = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // User accepted default behavior, so create registry key value
        regSettings.Write(_T("Print_Background"), _T("yes"));

        // Remember, reset it back to default value afterwards
        rbResetDefault = true;
    }
}

void CAvailableBrothersReportPreview::OnButtonPrintPreview() 
{

    CSettingsStore regSettings(false, false);

    if (regSettings.Open(_T("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Internet Explorer\\Main")))
    {
        CString strPrintBackground;
        BOOL bResetValue = FALSE, bResetResetDefault = FALSE;

        // Try to revise the Print_Background setting
        CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetPrintBackgroundSetting(regSettings, strPrintBackground,
            bResetResetDefault, bResetValue);

        // Now show the print preview dialogue
        if (m_pHtmlView != nullptr)
            m_pHtmlView->DoPrintPreview();

        // Reset the Print_Background setting if required
        if (bResetValue)
            regSettings.Write(_T("Print_Background"), strPrintBackground);
        else if (bResetResetDefault)
            regSettings.Write(_T("Print_Background"), _T("no"));
    }
}
```