# How to make background of the print page different from other print pages?

Tags: css, html

Is there any solution to make first page background different from other page background for print pages?

And also to make margins different for each pages?

I have tried different solutions but it didn't work; here is the solution I tried:

```
       @page {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        @page :first {
             background: none;
             margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        @media print {
            body {
                background: url('../img/background.jpg') repeat-y !important;
            }
        }
```

Comment: :first should definitely work, are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: You have little control over printing background images or colours for that matter. Default setting for printers are set to "don't print background images". However, here''s a great post about an alternative way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css

Comment: @SergChernata yes it applies to all pages rather than the first page only and background doesn't work at all on '@page :first'

Comment: @WimMertens I have read that but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Miheretab Alemu I know, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. I thought it would be useful to share.

Comment: As Serg mentioned, :first should work. Other than that we have no way of offering a solution with the information you've provided. A link would be useful perhaps?

Comment: I need some one to try this for me and help me what's wrong with the code provide a new solution?

Comment: Not sure if you want to get your code working or you want a solution, I would place all pages on it's own container and then force a page break upon printing at a specific div, so like this you can easily style the divs

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz I want a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this by using `:second`, as it doesn't seem to be a valid value.

See the [Index of standard pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first).

And even if you would use just :`first`, I don't think the background image can be applied as stated in the above link.

Since you already tried different solutions but it didn't work, here's a solution for you.

Depending on your sites layout and requirements, you can estimate where you want to break the page, and surround that in its own container so you have full control on them when being printed.

See example code:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
body{
   background-color: black;
   margin: 0px;
}
.page-break{
   height: 1054px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   position: relative;
}
#first{background-color: green;}
#second{background-color: pink;}
h1{
  padding-top: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   margin: 0px; //Add margin 0px for the first div in page-break
}
h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: lightblue;
}

@page {
    margin: 0;
}

@media print {
    html, body {
        //style body here
    }
.page-break{
       page-break-before: always;
   }    
    #first{
    background-color: maroon;  
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
   }
   #second{
    background-color: gray;
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
  #third{
       //style the third page;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-break" id="first">
   <h1>First Page header</h1>
   <h2>Some text here </h2> 
</div>

<div class="page-break" id="second">
   <h1>Second page header</h1>
   <h2>Some text here </h2>
</div>

<div class="page-break" id="third">
   <h1>Third page header</h1>
   <h2>Some text here </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if this is the closest answer, what I need is a background of the whole page including the margins. And the first page has a little bit of black background, I want all pages including margin covered with different background than the others.

Comment: I updated my code. You will have to play around to get it to work the way you want, but the idea is there.

Comment: Can you help me with something? the above works but when the first page has content more than one page it is printed on the second page without breaking from existing second page, it should be three pages if the pages content is grater than the first page content. how  can we fix that?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of what you have so far? Will modify accordingly.

Comment: You can use your own sample. I have used yours and just add additional content on the first page like <h1>additional text ...</h1>.

Comment: Oh. That's a simple fix playing around the margin accordingly. I'll  update the code when I get a chance to be at computer. (Replying from phone)

Comment: ok I just need to make new page if there is extra contents that overflow from page 1 and it shouldn't be mixed with page 2. I thought page-break-before would do it but it is not working.

Comment: Updated code in answer. I hope that's what you meant. With the updated code, you can keep on adding elements withing the page-break div.

Comment: No, that was not what I am looking for, anyways I found the solution, you can change it the answer the way it was before.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs about [`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page):

> You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be
>   ignored.

It looks like changing the background of the first printed page only (using `@page`) is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

build a function that will add a class to the first container, and then call the window.print() function.
the class will look something like that:

```
.div_with_bg {
height: 3508px; 
width: 2480px; 
background: url('../img/background.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-y;}
```