# Issue with loading tiles when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have an issue that  I don't understand. I have two containers each one 
 containes a map. My aim is to be able to print them,  to do so I used 
 window.print() yet the tiles are not being loaded when I move to printing 
 layout. If you have any idea about what is going on please tell me.

```js
var map1;
  var map2;
  $(document).ready(function(){
      map1 = L.map( 'map1', {
      center: [33.960057, -6.916462],
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true
      });
      L.tileLayer("https://stamen-tiles-c.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map1 );
      L.tileLayer("http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map1 );

      map2 = L.map( 'map2', {
      center: [33.960057, -6.916462],
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true
      });
      L.tileLayer("https://stamen-tiles-c.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map2 );
      L.tileLayer("http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map2 );

      map1.on("click",function (e) {
        var center = map1.getCenter();
        map2.flyTo(center);
      });
      window.print();


    });
```

```css
  html, body{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  #map1, #map2{
    height : 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  @media print {
  @page {
   size: landscape;
  }

  body *{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    color-adjust: exact !important;
    /*color:unset !important;
    color: transparent !important;*/
  }

}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
        <div id="map1"class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
        <div id="map2"class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```js
var map1;
  var map2;
  $(document).ready(function(){
      map1 = L.map( 'map1', {
      center: [33.960057, -6.916462],
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true
      });
      L.tileLayer("https://stamen-tiles-c.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map1 );
      L.tileLayer("http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map1 );

      map2 = L.map( 'map2', {
      center: [33.960057, -6.916462],
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true
      });
      L.tileLayer("https://stamen-tiles-c.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map2 );
      L.tileLayer("http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",{opacity:0.7}).addTo( map2 );

      map1.on("click",function (e) {
        var center = map1.getCenter();
        map2.flyTo(center);
      });
      window.print();


    });
```

```css
html, body{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  #map1, #map2{
    height : 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  @media print {
  @page {
   size: landscape;
  }

  body *{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    color-adjust: exact !important;
    /*color:unset !important;
    color: transparent !important;*/
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind+Siliguri" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
  </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
        <div id="map1"class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
        <div id="map2"class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: First guess would have been that those are maybe just background images - those do not get printed by default. But inspecting the example shows that these are just regular images - so maybe the stylesheet that comes with the map plugin explicitly hides them for print, or sth. like that, because they do not _want_ their maps to be printed out …?

Comment: it works when you put print in map1 onclick function, and you have to click on map one to get print.
so i seggust you to add a print button,

Comment: Yes this what I think the print is launched before the tiles get loaded.

Comment: The problem that I have is with bootstrap because strangely  when I  remove the import it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css)- is it of any help?
"With Chrome and Safari you can add the CSS style `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` to the element to force print the background color and/or image"

Comment: thanks for your reply, this property has been already used but no tile is displayed.

Comment: Does this help? Seems like it might be the same problem:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1741