# jQuery-generated bg images fail to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I'm baffled and I hope that it's only my lack of experience and/or knowledge.

I'm currently working on a simple app to generate a table with chosen (or random) background. Core code looks like this:

```js
let getRandomInt = (max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

$(document).ready( () => {

  $("#print").click( () => {
    $(".noprint").toggle();
    window.print();
    $(".noprint").toggle();
  });

  $("#generate").click( () => {
    let colourPick = $("#colour:checked").attr("value");

    // ignore getRandomInt, its defined outside of this event handler
  
    if (colourPick == "rand"){
      $("table.printedTable").css("background-image", `url("../static/bgs/${getRandomInt(9)}.gif")`);
    } else {
      $("table.printedTable").css("background-image", `url("../static/bgs/${colourPick}.gif")`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.printedTable {
  background-image: url("bgs/0.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.noprint {
  background-image: none;
}

div.colourSample{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.c0 {background-image: url("bgs/0.gif");}
.c1 {background-image: url("bgs/1.gif");}
.c2 {background-image: url("bgs/2.gif");}
.c3 {background-image: url("bgs/3.gif");}
.c4 {background-image: url("bgs/4.gif");}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="noprint">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="rand" checked> Random</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="0"> <div class="colourSample c0"></div></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="1"> <div class="colourSample c1"></div></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="2"> <div class="colourSample c2"></div></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="3"> <div class="colourSample c3"></div></td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="colour" value="4"> <div class="colourSample c4"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printedTable">
    <!-- An actual table to be printed -->
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolor</td>
      <td>Sit amat</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input id="generate" type="button" class="noprint" value="generate!">
  <input id="print" type="button" class="noprint" value="print!">
</div>
```

The problem here is that when I try to print the page (either with ctrl+p or print button there) no background images are showing on the table to be printed. Divs with colour samples - look fine, buttons (they have their css as well I just didnt include it) - great, but table is simply transparent no matter what. And it is the only jQuery-generated element on the page. What am I missing here? I know that by default most web browsers wont print bg images but I made sure that that's not the case here (I think - other backgrounds are showing).

Comment: Update: trying printing a static, just loaded page with default bg-img results in the same thing. So probably not a jQuery issue.

Comment: it's related particularly to the browser, which browser do you use?

Comment: also I forgot to mention that I'm using bootstrap in this project.

Comment: @Mohammad I don't think it's necessarily browser-related, because I'm testing it on Firefox and Chrome simultaneously. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.1, my main browser is Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

check this [color-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-adjust#Values)

> when printing, a browser might opt to leave out all background images and to adjust text colors to be sure the contrast is optimized for reading on white paper.

so you to add the following css properties to bypass this:

```
* {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari */
    color-adjust: exact !important;                 /*Firefox*/
}
```

[reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908040/2101939)