# print backpround images in kentiko

Tags: printing, background, kentico

I'm fairly new to Kentico and I'm trying to create a prepeater for print form .
i need to print form with **background image** .
pls help me . 
my code is :

http://prs.bimehasia.ir/%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D9%87%D8%A7/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%AD-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%87/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%84/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4%DB%8C/04.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
      
        
          
            
            
              
                
                گواهینامه دوره آموزشی
                شماره:  <%# IfEmpty(Eval("CertificateID"), "", Eval("CertificateID"))%>
              
              
                
                <%# GetCatName1(Eval("CertType"))%>
                تاریخ:  <%# CustomFunctions.GetDate(ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(Eval("CertDate"), DateTime.Now),"yyyy/MM/dd") %>
              
              
                گواهی میشود :
                
                
              
            
            
          
        
        
          
            
            
              
                سرکار خانم / جناب آقای :   
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("prsFullName"),  " " , Eval("prsFullName"))%>
                با شماره پرسنلی   
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("prscode"),  " " , "  " + Eval("prscode"))%>
                دوره آموزشی   
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("CourseName"),  " " , "  " + Eval("CourseName"))%>
              
            
            
          
        
        
          
            
            
              
                را در تاریخ
                <%# CustomFunctions.GetDate(ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(Eval("EndDate"), DateTime.Now),"yyyy/MM/dd") %>
                و به مدت
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("Courselength"),  " " , Eval("Courselength"))%>
                ساعت در
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("TrainingName"),  " " , Eval("TrainingName"))%>
                استان
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("Provincename"),  " " , Eval("Provincename"))%>
                شعبه
                ---
              
            
            
          
        
        
          
            
            
              
                با موفقیت به پایان رسانیده است.
              
            
            
          
        
        
          
            
            
              
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("DevelopManagerName"),  " " , Eval("DevelopManagerName"))%>
                <%# IfEmpty(Eval("AssistanceDevelopName"),  " " , Eval("AssistanceDevelopName"))%>
              
              
                معاون توسعه و برنامه ریزی
                مدیر طرح و توسعه

```
  <!---اسکریپت ها --->
  <script runat="server">
    string GetCatName1(object Name)
      {
        var input = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(Name, 0);
        switch(input)
        {
          case(1): return "(کارکنان)";
          default: return "(شبکه فروش و نمایندگان)";
        }
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: This is the English StackOverflow, please only speak English on this site so we're able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Printing (or not printing) of background images are in control of your browser and its settings. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css) for more details.