# windows.print() - background to preview window but not to print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF.
I create a PDF that registers input text in a specific layout.

With this, is their a way to have a background image in the print preview window BUT not actually print the background?

(for printing registration basically).

The paper has a pattern and the print call from Javascript positions the elements to print correctly, but the preview showing the background image and the items registered would be very useful.

I can either:
a) create a PDF (jsPDF) that has a non printing background? <- Ideal
b) Or is their a way to use the .print() functions to do so?

Thank you for everyone's time.

Comment: See if anything from  this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css

Comment: What about setting the background with a class ? When the users converts to PDF, remove the class, convert to PDF, re add the class ?

Comment: Thank you everyone - I edited the question slightly - pardon that. So I'm generating the PDF to certain parameters with jsPDF. Ideally I can set the background image as non-printing, which I believe is a normal setting for PDFs...

Comment: Arnaud Do you by chance have a concrete example of what you are talking about?