HTML span element is not printed
I am creating a custom colored legend and I tried adding <span> with custom CSS to create a round circle with background-color as in the example.
The print preview and actual PDF print of the browser ( Chromium at least ) does not display them.


.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
<span class="dot"></span>



That is strange and I would like to know the why and maybe how to fix it.

Did you select the Background Graphics option in the print dialog?

No, I did not know that.
Can I pre-enable this option by default for my users?

This answer looks like it solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css

This actually solves the problem, we could mark as duplicate maybe.

By default, browsers do not print backgrounds to save ink.
Your element only has a background (no border, no content...) so it is totally not showing on the print preview (but still takes space).
If you add text above and below your element, it will be easier to see:

On the webpage:

On the print preview:


If you really want to print them (for example if you are saving the page as a PDF), you must expand the "More settings" section in the print dialog and check the "Print backgrounds" option (or "Background graphics" on Google Chrome).


Could someone add a screenshot for Google Chrome?
