# Loading map marker issue in take print

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to point the marker on the map and it is visible on the browser. But when I print the same, the marker isn't visible on the map. Please help.

```
<button class="map-print" ng-click="mapprint();">print</button>
[enter image description here][1]<script>
function mapprint(){
    var content = document.getElementById('map_div'); //has to be first. 
    content.style.position = "relative"; 
    content.style.height = contents.firstChild.offsetHeight + "px"; 
    content.style.width = contents.firstChild.offsetWidth + "px"; 
    var win = window.open(); 
    win.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    win.print();
    win.close();    
}
```

I got print of the map. But canot load the map marker

this is my web view

[image]

This is my Map print view

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Google Map markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730767/how-to-print-google-map-markers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing is not supported by Google Maps JavaScript API. Have a look at the following answer in the official FAQ

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#print

> Printing from the JavaScript API is not supported. This is because printing support is inconsistent across commonly used browsers. We recommend using the Static Maps API for printing purposes.